# Custom pagename permalinks showing 404

Tags: wordpress

On WordPress, I am able to use the default permalink, eg /?page_id=123.
But not the pretty /pagename

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Permalink Settings (Settings > Permalinks ) to regenerate your .htaccess file

Comment: On Permalink Settings, /index.php/pagename works but not /page

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
WordPress was ignoring the .htaccess.
Need to amend httpd.conf such that AllowOverride is "All".
Initial value should be "None".